# How to run a loop with unknown number of iterations in Circom?

Tags: circuit, circom, zk-snark, zkp

I have the following circuit in [Circom cicuit compiler](https://docs.circom.io/):

```
pragma circom 2.0.0;

template MAIN() {

    signal len;
    len <== 32;

    for (k = 0; k < maplen; k++) { 
        // do something
    }

}

component main = MAIN();
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error[T2005]: Typing error found
    ┌─ "/Users/ilia/compiling/main-circom/circuits/main.circom":118:17
    │
118 │     for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    │                 ^^^^^^^ There are constraints depending on the value of the condition and it can be unknown during the constraint generation phase
```

How do I write this loop in a way which makes it possible to iterate `len` times where `len` is a signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide how many maximum iterations your loop can have (an iteration budget) and then discard all the iterations you don't need using `LessThan` component. You can also select the needed result of a iteration using `QuinSelector`